# Laravel storage не сохраняет файлы на хостинге ,что можно сделать?

Tags: php, laravel

На локальном сервере Laravel storage работает правильно, но на хостинге storage не сохраняет файлы,

```
Storage::disk('public')->putFile($folderDir, $uploadImage)
```

результат этого кода,строка, путь файла,  ни каких ошибок не выводится путь файла хранится в базе данных, но самого файла нету соответственно изображение не показывается на экран.

Использую платный хостинг Hostinger.ru.
На хостинге переименовал public папку на public_html,  символическая ссылка storage работает правильно.

Comment: возможно, проблема с доступом. Но тогда странно, почему у вас ошибок нет.

Comment: с доступом к чему ,у меня хостинг платный премиум

Comment: С доступом в каталог сохранения файла. Там может быть не тот владелец выставлен или нет прав на запись

Comment: А как узнать это если ошибки не выводятся ?

Comment: линуксовая команда `ls`

Comment: Отправить команду через  ssh или есть другой способ ?  На хостинге в файловом менеджере есть  раздел permissions там storage  имеет эти разрешения   drw-r--r-- (644).

Comment: Посмотрите владельца каталога. Для apache он должен быть `www-data`

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вы забыли выполнить на хостинге команду:

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

Это из laravel-специфичных ошибок, подробнее [в документации](http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/filesystem).

Из общих ошибок - нет прав на запись в каталог storage.

По-хорошему нужно сначала установить владельцем пользователя, от которого запущен веб-сервер (apache (RHEL-дистрибутивы типа Centos) или www-data (Debian-based дистрибутивы) -- в разных дистрибутивах по-разному), а потом уже проверять права на папки.

Только я не рекомендую устанавливать 777, как автор соседнего ответа -- лучше делайте по уму: 644 для файлов и 755 для папок. А 777 - это плохо с точки зрения безопасности.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй sudo chmod -R 777 storage/

Comment: это вредный совет.